# Get a key equal to an item from SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, key, sorteddictionary, string-interning

Is there any way to retrieve a key from a SortedDictionary that is equal to a given object?  To illustrate, lets say I create a dictionary that has a fairly memory-heavy, immutable key type:

```
var dictionary = SortedDictionary<MyHugeType, int>();
var myEnormousKey = new MyHugeType();

dictionary[myEnormousKey] = 123;
```

Then later on, I do something like this:

```
// This is a new instance, but it's identical to the previous key
var myIdenticalKey = new MyHugeType();

if(dictionary.ContainsKey(myIdenticalKey)) {
    myIdenticalKey = dictionary.GetKeyEqualTo(myIdenticalKey);
}

// Use myIdenticalKey reference...
```

Obviously, SortedDictionary does not have a "GetKeyEqualTo" method.  But is there some way I could achieve a similar effect?  This would basically have the effect of intern-ing the heavy key objects so that identical instances could be discarded.  I know I can do this using the SortedList class by retrieving the key's index and subsequently its matching object instance, but SortedDictionary's consistent insertion performance would be better for my uses.

Short of iterating through all the dictionary's keys to search for a match, or writing my own BST class, is there any way to achieve this end with .NET's built in collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your value object from int to a struct or class containing both the value and the original key. Then to access the original key you can do:

```
dictionary[myIdenticalKey].OriginalKey
```

and for the value something like:

```
dictionary[myIdenticalKey].Value
```

Comment: Now there's an idea. :-)  I might go for that barring any more direct solutions.

Comment: Looks like that's the best I can do without rewriting the class to expose the desired feature.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `IEquatable` interface in your key class. There you specify when two objects of the class are equal to each other. After that you simply test the existence of an entry using `ContainsKey` and when that returns `true` you can obtain it using the `[]` operator.

You could also provide a `IComparer` implementation to achieve the same result.

Comment: But the [] operator of SortedDictionary returns the _value_ associated with the key.  I need the key itself.

Comment: The key is the one your are currently working with, since the method states they are equal. If they are equal you can use your current key as you would your previous key object. If you really need the original key you should change your implementation like @aKzenT suggested.

Comment: But there are still two (or possibly more in this application) object instances.  I want to eliminate the reference to all but one of them, similar to the string.Intern() method, only not using strings.  (aKzenT's method should work though.)

Comment: With the solution of @aKzenT you always have two instances per entry in your dictionary: one for the key and one in the value. With the equals method you only have the instance in dictionary and every instance you use for searching and/or testing is disposed when the appropriate method is finished.

Comment: aKzenT's method only needs to store one instance per entry.  When storing the entry initially, I would do something like "dictionary[myHugeKey] = new Tuple(myHugeKey, myValue)".  Then I can use a separate (but identical) key to retrieve the equal one in the dictionary and discard the duplicate.  There are two _references_ to the key per entry, but both references point to a single _instance_. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in `MyHugeType` with code that determines if two instances are the same, then you won't get duplicate keys in the dictionary. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Or implement `IEquatable` as Osiris76 says.